# setTimeout Functionality in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to understand the concept of `setTimeout` and I couldn't understand how it works. In the below example, when I gave the 1000 to the second `setTimeout` function I got the output as

1)Hello 567
2)Hello
3)Hello 123

But When I gave the `setTimeout` for all the functions as 0, it shows as

1)Hello 123
2)Hello 567
3)Hello

Initially, I assumed the innerfunction value is returned first then in the below case shouldn't be

1)Hello 567
2)Hello 123
3)Hello

Please help me understand

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hello");
      }, 0, setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hello 123");
      }, 0), setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hello 567");
      }, 0));
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your first `setTimeout` is not correctly closed... you provide it more than 2 arguments, which will be evaluated as arguments to pass to the callback. I don't think you intended that.

Comment: Do you know what the third (and fourth and so on) argument to [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is used for? The output `Hello 123`, then `Hello 567`, then `Hello` makes sense, since the inner arguments need to be evaluated before the outer function call. This is always the case and is not specific to `setTimeout`. The only special thing about `setTimeout` is that a delay of `0` attempts to schedule function execution in the next event loop cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure whether this was intentional or a typo, but you're passing more than two arguments to the first `setTimeout`. I've deconstructed your code for clarity. This is what you're doing:

```js
function hello () {
  alert("Hello");
}

function hello123 () {
  alert("Hello 123");
}

function hello567 () {
  alert("Hello 567");
}

setTimeout(hello, 0, setTimeout(hello123, 0), setTimeout(hello567, 0));
```

You're passing 4 arguments to the outer `setTimeout` call. The last two are evaluated first to resolve their values before being passed to (the outer/first) `setTimeout`.

setTimeout returns an ID, so if the inner calls return 555555 and 999999 respectively, this is the equivalent of:

```js
setTimeout(hello, 0, 555555, 999999)
```

And because the inner calls get evaluated first you see those alerts first if they all have the same delay<sup>1</sup>.

If you increase the delay on the inner timeouts you'll see their alerts after, because the outer one expires first.

---

<sub>1. Due to the way timeouts are handled in the javascript event loop, it's *possible* that these could appear in a different order. I'm ignoring those idiosyncracies for the purposes of this discussion.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're expecting by passing a third and fourth parameter to `setTimeout`, but it obviously evaluates before the root `setTimeout`.

To clarify, the 3rd and 4th parameters of the root `setTimeout` are the results of other `setTimeout` calls, so they need to be evaluated first before their results are passed the the root `setTimeout`.

Comment: To clarify, the result of the second setTimeout (which is a timeout identifier), is needed for the root setTimeout as it's one of its parameters.  //// Help me understand , this is where I got confused. Here the 3 rd alert should come as first & then second alert right?

Comment: I'm explaining the current behavior of your code which makes no sense. Could you explain what you are actually trying to achieve so I can make a better answer?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the concept of setTimeout in deeper :)

Comment: @HemaNandagopal _“Here the 3 rd alert should come as first & then second alert right?”_ — No, the timeout with `alert("Hello 123");` is evaluated _before_ the one with `alert("Hello 567");`. If you expect it to be the other way around and still use this confusing structure with nested functions, move the `)` after the second `0` to the end.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I got it now. So when I gave 1000 to second setTimeout it was loading after 1st and 3rd because of the time and not because of the order of function execution right?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal you should take a look at the other answer because your problem might be related to a silly typo

Comment: @GuerricP , Yes I was trying to understand the concepts and that mistake which I made makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal As you can see from the documentation here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp, setTimeout only takes 2 parameters: the function to call and the number of MILLIseconds to wait.

Comment: @raphael75 this doc is actually incomplete, the following parameters are actually passed to the callback after the delay

Comment: @GuerricP That page does show that additional parameters can be passed a little farther down in the "Parameter Values" section.

Comment: @raphael75 The proper documentation link (to MDN, a reputable source) has already been linked above.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close out the first `setTimeout()` call with `)`.

You can now see that they run in the sequence that they were invoked, which is the sequence that they are placed on the event queue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hello 1");
      }, 0)
      , setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hello 2");
      }, 0)
      , setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Hello 3");
      }, 0);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```